# Rails – How to use if else statement in array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, api, if-statement

I'm integrating infusionsoft with our rails app and we can create contacts using their API using this call, and passing the data through an array...

```
Infusionsoft.contact_add_with_dup_check({'Email' => contact.email, 'FirstName' => (contact.name if contact.name.present?)}, 'Email')
```

However, I want to be able to post additional contact info to their API if the contact in our rails app has more data. Such as if `name`  or `city` is present. My attempt at checking if contact.name is present returns an error.

How can I do an if else statement within the array?

Comment: It can be like FirstName' => contact.name.present? ? contact.name : ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
contact_info = {'Email' => contact.email}
contact_info.merge!({'FirstName' => contact.name }) if contact.name.present?
Infusionsoft.contact_add_with_dup_check(contact_info, 'Email')
```

you can use a code same as in line#2 in case of `city`

Comment: Brilliant idea! Learned something new too. Thanks